# Elasticsearch Group By Aggregation with Filtering Performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having a performance problem with Elasticsearch (6.3). There are 1B documents in my index, and I need to do an aggregation against a small subset of the data.

My index looks like

```
    "s-data": {
        "mappings": {
            "s-type": {
                "properties": {
                    "c": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "r": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "s": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "t": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my query looks like

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {"term":{"t": "foo"}},
                {"term":{"c": 1}},
                {"terms":{"r": ["foobar", "foobaz"]}},
                {"term":{"s": 3}}
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "recips":{
          "terms": {"field": "r"}
        }
    }
}
```

The query itself runs in 15ms, but once I tack on the aggregation the whole thing just times out. I assume that the aggregation is running against the entire 1B doc dataset. How can I make the aggregation run only against the results of my query?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html):

```
{
    "aggs":{
        "recips_subset": {
           "filter":[
                {"term":{"t": "foo"}},
                {"term":{"c": 1}},
                {"terms":{"r": ["foobar", "foobaz"]}},
                {"term":{"s": 3}}
            ],
            "aggs": {
                "recips":{
                    "terms": {"field": "r"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**However**, this should have the same effect as your original query, since aggregations execute within the context of the executed query/filters of the search request. So to find the real bottleneck more information is needed:

- What is the [cardinality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) of the field `r`?
- Did you modify the `size` parameter or have you used a script instead of a field?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The cardinality of r in the whole dataset is on the order of 100M, however for this particular query it's 2 (foobar, foobaz). The size of the result set from this particular query is 4 (2 per r value). I have tried the filter agg, with unchanged results as you say. Setting size to 0 has no effect.

Comment: This issue which has been fixed in version 6.4.0 looks related: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/30117

Comment: Hmm interesting - there should only be the two buckets in this case, so I'm not sure this applies. I will look into upgrading however, that is always a good idea

Comment: If I understand correctly this is exactly the issue quoted there - it loops through the entire bucket set instead of the matching ones. Quoting from the discussion there: "I agree this is a performance bug and defeats the purpose of using a hash table to collect matching ordinals."

Comment: In any case I'm not familiar with the code to tell if this issue in fact affects you, but as you said upgrading is a good idea. Good luck, and I would love to hear if it helped.

Comment: Oh I see it now in the pr "Though when building the final buckets, this aggregator loops over all possible global ordinals
rather than using the hash map that was built to remap the ordinals."

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will upgrade and let you know